# Oauth2.0 auhtorization server configuration

Tags: java, spring, rest, oauth

I'm creating a protected rest apis based on oauth2.0 framework.

I built the **Authorization server** and the **Resource server** successfully.

The **AuthorizationServer** extends **AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter**
and overrides some methods, i'm facing a problem with this extended method

> **public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {}**

Here is the explanation

When i'm running this version of the **config()** **Authorization Server**

```
    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

        clients.inMemory().withClient("clientapp").authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                .scopes("read", "write").resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID).secret("123456");

   }
```

this method works just fine and returns an access_token when i ask for it.

But when i ran the same method with some enhancements, i got nothing when i asked for access_token but 401 unauthorized http response.

```
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    int n = appMetier.getAppsCount();
    for (App app:appMetier.findAll(0, n).getApps()) {
        clients.inMemory().withClient(app.getClientPublicId()).authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                .scopes("read", "write").resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID).secret(app.getClientSecretId());
    }
  }
```

The n variable here equals to 17, it means i have 17 clients in Memory who have the right receive an access_token.

The only one who gets the access_token from the 17 is the first one.

Your answers please and thanks in advance.

Comment: You need multiple clients for the same OAuth provider ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `inMemory()` multiple times, that overwrites the builder service every time. It should be called only once.

Following code should work.

```
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    int n = appMetier.getAppsCount();
    InMemoryClientDetailsServiceBuilder clientBuilder = clients.inMemory();

    for (App app:appMetier.findAll(0, n).getApps()) {
        clientBuilder.withClient(app.getClientPublicId()).authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
            .scopes("read", "write").resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID).secret(app.getClientSecretId());
    }
}
```